# Selectively disable exceptions on specific files on c++

Tags: c++, exception

I'm working on integrating a sub-module `sm` to a larger project `p`.

The integration happens by adding the source code of `sm` into `p` and compiling all together (which is performed by a quite-complicated multi-platform build system).

These two parts come from different vendors. `sm` throws exceptions (a lot), but `p` has them disabled (and I can not change that). Because of this, I'm running into a lot of trouble when compiling, getting lots of `error : exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable`. Enabling the exceptions is not an option, and change the source files would be problematic.

Is there a way to disable exceptions on `sm` without having to modify `p` or the original code?

Note there is a `#pragma` to selectively disable warnings. Is there something similar to disable exceptions? 
Maybe something like this:

```
//source file of main project [code.h]

//Something disables exceptions here
//#pragma disable exceptions??
#include <submodule.h>
//Restore
//#pragma enable exceptions??
#include <...>

//code
```

Comment: If you expect the compiler to just disable exceptions in `sm`, what would happen to the code `throw err;`?

Comment: My guess is that you're stuck. Even if you disabled exceptions in sm, if, during runtime, sm executes an instruction to throw an exception (or omits the throw somehow) it leaves the execution in an undefined state.

Comment: Most of the exceptions are thrown because of bad formatted data, which I already check before each call to the sub-module functions, so its not too difficult to prevent them from being thrown. If it is possible to handle the exceptions gracefully would be a win, but just halting the hole program is still acceptable on my case.

Comment: Surround all function calls with `try` / `catch (...)` is not an option?

Comment: @ChristianHackl No, when you have disabled the exceptions, you are not allowed to "handle" them. Most of the compiler errors I got come from try/catch blocks.

Comment: @Xocoatzin: You are right, I missed the part with "compiling them all together".